# Find the top 80 Pct of Products Per Store

Tags: sql-server

I have to create a query to find the top 80 percent of sold products per store. Is there a way to do this using a windowing function? My table is a transactional data set with following columns:

```
StoreID | ProductID | NoOfProducts | SoldDate
```

For one store, if there were a 100 different products sold `COUNT(DISTINCT(ProductID))`, I'd expect to get a result set of 80 products for that store. How could I do this? (My DB environment is SQL Server 2008)

Comment: Did you try SELECT TOP(80)PERCENT, ordered by COUNT(DISTINCT(ProductID))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work using `ROW_NUMBER()` and then using the `COUNT` per each store to determine which rows to display.  This will always display the first 80% sorted by ProductId:

```
SELECT 
  t.StoreId,
  t.ProductId,
  t.rn
FROM (
    SELECT StoreId, 
         ProductId, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY StoreId ORDER BY ProductId) rn
    FROM YourTable ) t JOIN (
    SELECT StoreId,
         COUNT(DISTINCT ProductId) cnt
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY StoreId
  ) t2 on t.StoreId = t2.StoreId
WHERE t.rn <= (t2.cnt*.8)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b4a6/7)

Comment: This is a decent answer. I was able to use NTILE(100) to split up the ProductIDs and filter it out that way as well. Thanks!